# How do I make a new String based on another string's unknown length?

Tags: java, string, substring

I am currently in a computer programming class and at a dead end for "creating a template" for this 2-person hang man game.

- First, person#1 is prompted for a phrase (contains all lowercase)
- Then, I must take whatever phrase they choose and turn it into a template with all ?'s.
- Then, as person#2 guesses letters, I must "reveal" the phrase and have the ?'s turn into the phrase letters.

I can't get past turning it into the template though. An example is:

person#1's phrase: "hello world"

desired template outcome: "????? ?????"

This is what I have so far... I'm having trouble at public static String createTemplate(String sPhrase)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program9 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner (System.in);

    int cnt = 0; //counter is set to zero
    String sPhrase;
    boolean def;

    System.out.print("Enter a phrase consisting of only lowercase letters and spaces: ");
    sPhrase = scanner.nextLine(); //reads into variable set to Scanner.nextLine()


    System.out.println("\n\n\nCommon Phrase");
        System.out.println("--------------\n");

        String template = createTemplate(sPhrase); //will run through "createTemplate" and show whatever on there.

    do
    {

        char guess = getGuess(stdIn); //will run through "getGuess" and show whatever SOP and return from that. WORKS.

        cnt = cnt + 1; //counts the guess

        System.out.println("\n\n\nCommon Phrase");
        System.out.println("--------------\n");

        String updated = updateTemplate(template, sPhrase, guess); //runs throuhgh and prints updated template




    } while (!exposedTemplate(sPhrase)); //will loop back if updated template still has ?'s



    System.out.println("Good job! It took you " + cnt + " guesses!");
}
public static String createTemplate(String sPhrase)
{
    String template = null;
    String str;


    sPhrase.substring(0, sPhrase.length()+1); //not sure if +1 needed.
    sPhrase.equals(template);

    //THIS IS WHERE IM HAVING PROBLEMS



}
public static char getGuess(Scanner stdIn)
{
    //repeatedly prompts user for char response in range of 'a' to 'z'
    String guess;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a lowercase letter guess : ");
        guess = stdIn.next();
    } while (Character.isDigit(guess.charAt(0)));

    char firstLetter = guess.charAt(0);
    return firstLetter;
}

public static String changeCharAt(String str, int ind, char newChar)
{
    return str.substring(0, ind) + newChar + str.substring(ind+1);
    //freebie: returns copy of str with chars replaced

}
public static String updateTemplate(String template, String sPhrase, char guess)
{
    //will have to include changeCharAt


}
public static boolean exposedTemplate(String template)
{
    // returns true exactly when there are no more ?'s

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
public static String createTemplate(String sPhrase)
{
    return sPhrase.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "?");
}
```

the `replaceAll` method of the [`String` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) in Java replaces all parts of the string that match the supplied regular expression with a string (in this case `?`)

Learning regular expressions (known as regexes) may not be in the scope of this assignment, but is a very useful skill for all computer programmers. In this example I've used the regular expression [a-zA-Z] which means replace any upper or lower case character, however you could also use a character class like `\\w`.

There is an excellent tutorial on Java regexes here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: @Michelle Schroeder If this solution worked for you, no need to say thanks, just click the Tick next to the answer to indicate to future readers that this code solved your problem. Glad to be of help.

Comment: I know its been 8 years, but I just wanted to say thank you. I asked this question on here and then forgot about it until now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a `for-loop`, you'll need to check each character of the phrase, `String#charAt` should help.  If the character is not a space, you would append an `?` to the template, otherwise you'll need to append a space...

See [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sPhrase.length());
for (int index = 0; index < sPhrase.length(); index++) {
    if (sPhrase.charAt(index) != ' ') {
        sb.append("?");
    } else {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}
sTemplate = sb.toString();
```

Equally you could use...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sPhrase.length());
for (char c : sPhrase.toCharArray()) {
    if (c != ' ')) {
        sb.append("?");
    } else {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}
sTemplate = sb.toString();
```

But I thought the first one would be easier to understand...

Answer (score -1):

Just use a regex and String.replaceAll() method:

```
public static String createTemplate(String sPhrase)
{
    return sPhrase.replaceAll(".", "?");
}
```

In this example, the first parameter is a regex, so "." matches all characters. The second parameter is the string to replace all regex matches with, a "?".

Comment: The `.` replace is almost never a good idea. In this case, you will replace spaces and hyphens in the original text with a question mark, ie. "ANNA-MAE" would become "????????" which would not be correct for a hangman game where only letters can be guessed.

Comment: easy enough to change the regex to pick out characters only, or whatever match you want.. I said the "." matches ALL characters, just change it to [a-zA-Z] or whatever...

Comment: True, but as currently written, this solution doesn't work for the "hello world" example posted in the question.